# Replicate radiating circles like user location on MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview, core-location

Is it possible to have the radiating circles like the user location annotation. So that custom annotations have radiating circles of other colors. If not is there a hack way to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out. You may able to do what you need with that. With a combination of using Core Animation and subclassing `MKCircleView` or `MKOverlayView`.

http://yickhong-ios.blogspot.com/2012/04/animated-circle-on-mkmapview.html

Comment: That is absolutely what I was looking for, I edited it a bit and instead of using an image I created the image with the graphics context instead. Thanks so much that is awesome

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create a custom subclass of UIView that does this.  A UIView with two sublayers, one for the center ball and one for the expanding rings.  The ring layer and the ball layer can be created by subclassing CALayer and overriding drawInContext: so you can get any colors you want.  Code to animate the rings so that they expand and fade out at the same time could use a CAAnimationGroup like this:

```
// expand the ring from the ball size to the ring's max size
CABasicAnimation *sizeAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];
sizeAnim.fromValue   = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:ballBounds];
sizeAnim.toValue     = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:ringBoundsMax];
sizeAnim.duration    = kRingExpansionTime;

// fade out the ring part way thru the animation
CABasicAnimation* alphaAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
alphaAnim.fromValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1];
alphaAnim.toValue     = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
alphaAnim.beginTime   = kRingExpansionTime * 0.7f;      // start part way thru
alphaAnim.duration    = kRingExpansionTime - alphaAnim.beginTime;

CAAnimationGroup* group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
group.duration    = kRingExpansionTime;
group.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;      // repeat forever
group.animations  = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sizeAnim, alphaAnim, nil];
[ringLayer addAnimation:group forKey:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if it is possible to put this in a MKAnnotation/MKOverlay so that it is scaleable as you zoom in/out?